# Why is my phone not charging, and the lightning cable burning hot?

Tags: iphone, usb, battery, charging

My phone has been charging on and off. What happens is it charges fine for about 5-10%, then stops charging all together. I think it is a phone issue because i have tried on 2 different sockets with 2 different chargers and cables. One of the chargers is making abnormal, high pitched noises as it is plugged it. I just noticed that one of the cables was burning hot about 30 seconds after it started charging, I'm talking so hot you wouldnt be able to hold a finger to it for 500 milliseconds before you involuntarily move your hand away (not as hot as a stove though). What is the problem here?

Comment: Excessive heat would make me believe that there is some short-circuit. Are you sure that only the cable gets hot, not the phone? Because if its only the cable I would also guess that its actually the cable thats broken.

Comment: Take a look inside the lightning port on your phone and see if there's any crud in there that might be shorting it out or causing a bad connection. If there is, be very careful cleaning it out -- you don't want to damage the contacts (any more than they already are)!